# android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

When I intent to excute the thirdactivity.class, Logcat says this, what does that mean?
the activity has been built through.
but when emulate, the prog stopped.

```
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at com.example.andrappexp1.ThirdActivity$2.onItemSelected(ThirdActivity.java:58)
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-11 10:17:25.824: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the spinner in the thirdactivity.class is like this,

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);  
this.mAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Cities,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
spinner.setAdapter(this.mAdapter); 
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener(){ 

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"The planet is " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
        textViewa.setText("You choose :"+ " " + mAdapter.getItem(arg2)); 
        arg0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
    }  

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
        textViewa.setText("NONE");    
        arg0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
    }    
});
```

As I suspected that the statement of textviewa is really a problem. I change it into toast, like this one:

```
toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Defined Toast",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG); toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 
toast.show();
```

and all is ok.

**Now I find the cause that I forget to bind txtview from Id. it's my carelessness. and now add the statement**:

```
TextView textViewa=(TextView) findViewById(R.Id.textView1);
```

they are showing perfectly. 
Thank you at the same.

Comment: post your activity code!

Comment: I try to add more code, but click save button no respond, whats matter

Comment: I suspect this statement,textViewa.setText("You choose :"+  is matter. how shall I write a output text on screen?

Comment: ya! because this is illegal way! mAdapter.getItem(arg2);

Comment: what do you want to achieve on click?

Comment: So it is. The statement of textviewa is really a problem. I change it into toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Defined Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); toast.show(); and all is ok.

Comment: Hamad, Thank you at the same.

Comment: maybe your `textView` is null :O

Answer (score 1):

ok then Use this code to get Spinner selection:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            System.out.println();
            textViewa.setText("You choose :"+ " " + ((TextView) arg1).getText().toString()); 

        }
```

Comment: I forget to write the find from Id. now add: TextView textViewa=(TextView) findViewById(R.Id.textView1); they are showing perfectly.

Comment: Hamad, if there is no such statement, it is still stopped. I shall change it into new correct states. than k you at the same.

Answer (score 1):

Now I find the cause that I forget to bind txtview from Id. it's my carelessness. and now add the statement:

```
TextView textViewa=(TextView) findViewById(R.Id.textView1);
```

they are showing perfectly. Thank you at the same.